# how to put comparison date validation outside tag form i use (datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i put my datepicker in section tag

```
<section class="dsr_event layout" id="eventLayout">
    <input type=text class='input_date_from input_date'  readonly=readonly /> ~ 
   <input type=text class='input_date_to input_date' readonly=readonly />
</section>
```

in my javascript

```
 var fromdate = from[0].split("/");
                     var datefrom = new Date($.trim(fromdate[0]),$.trim(fromdate[1])-1,$.trim(fromdate[2]));
                     $('.input_date_from',parent).datepicker();
                     $('.input_date_from',parent).datepicker("option","dateFormat","yy-mm-dd");
                     $('.input_date_from',parent).datepicker("setDate",datefrom);
                     var todate = from[1].split("/");
                     var to_date = new Date($.trim(todate[0]),$.trim(todate[1])-1,$.trim(todate[2]));
                     $('.input_date_to',parent).datepicker();
                     $('.input_date_to',parent).datepicker("option","dateFormat","yy-mm-dd");
                     $('.input_date_to',parent).datepicker("setDate",to_date);
```

i want to make validation two date before/after comparison these two date i try to other plugin but doesn't work. please help me with this thanks in advance